# How do geologists examine mountains and hills inwardly?

Tags: geology, mountains

There is an idyllic verdant valley where I live, full of mountains and hills. Most mountains are covered by vegetation, but some have flat steppe-like tops where people have small farms and homesteads. There is this particular mountain that has a farm on top that is for sale; even though the foot of the mountain is full of trees and bushes, when I get closer to the edge on top I can see there are rocky parts which the current owner told me was basalt. I can also see random rocky spots engulfed by grass and flowers on top; actually such spots are scattered across the farm. I wonder if I could hire a geologist to inspect the internal part of the mountain. Can a geologist tell me how much of it is made of basalt and how much of it is just dirt? How about the depth of such layers? Does such an examination exist? If so, how does it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geological_survey